# Como deletar um arquivo sem extensão , pelo SHELL

Tags: vb.net

No visual basic eu uso esse comando e consigo deletar todos os arquivos dentro da pasta cache do google chrome como no exemplo abaixo :

Shell("CMD.exe /c DEL /q ""%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache*.*"" ")

[[ Porém o que eu quero deletar está dentro dessa pasta .
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\
é o arquivo chamado simplesmente de history sem extensão sem nada ; Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço .]] Tem uma print URL para exemplificar

Para facilitar tirei uma print
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR2de.png

Obrigado a todos que puderem ajudar .

Assim deleta normal
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Users\Mauricio Perroni\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History") * Funciona mais só deleta no meu usuário não serve para todos.

Mais só dá no meu pc ; porque está com o meu usuário se eu coloco %USERNAME% que é a variável do meu usuário ele não executa o comando .

Comment: @Bacco sabe a resposta disso ?

Comment: Tente: `Shell("CMD.exe /c DEL /q ""%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache*"" ")`

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira não é o cache que eu quero deletar não é o arquivo History que tá dentro da pasta DEFAULT .

Usei o cache para dar exemplo .

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira negócio que o arquivo não tem extensão por isso ele pensa que o comando é uma pasta .
saca se eu colocar assim 
Shell("CMD.exe /c DEL ""%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History.rar"" ")

ele deleta o arquivo porque tem extensão se não não deleta porque não tem extensão .

Comment: Primeiro vc tem que ter certeza se o arquivo não está sendo usado, senão não vai deletar mesmo. Talvez você tenha que rodar 2x o comando, uma vez com * e outra com \*.\* (teste e veja o que acontece). Ainda acho que um loop em VB faria um serviço melhor do que chamar o shell.

Comment: @Bacco ele não tá deletando porque tá entendendo que o History é uma pasta e não um arquivo sem extensão o que ele é .

Comment: @Perroni não tem sentido isso, o OS não tem essas crises de consciência. Pasta é pasta, arquivo é arquivo. Ou a aplicação não tem permissão sobre o arquivo, ou ele está em uso. Veja aqui como o del com um `*` só funciona bem para deletar arquivos sem extensao, acabei de rodar um teste: **http://i.stack.imgur.com/McRER.png** (os amarelinhos eu marquei manualmente, com a ferramenta de captura _Snipping Tool_ do windows 7) **Dica:** eu pus um arquivo COM extensão e fiz o teste novamente, o `*` serviu para apagar todos, com e sem extensão, provavelmente no seu caso pode trocar o `*.*` por `*`.

Comment: @Bacco tem teamviewer ai ?

Comment: @Bacco queria te mostrar , seria mais simples.
Quando eu uso esse comando abaixo : 
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Users\Mauricio Perroni\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History")

Ele delete desde que o chrome fique fechado, mais isso depois eu resolvo com um taskkill.

o problema do comando que funciona é que tenho que tirar o meu nome da linha e colocar %USERNAME% ai quando coloco o vb não aceita a variável de sistema.

Comment: @Bacco Vou dar um jeito de fazer um vídeo aqui .

Comment: @Perroni aí é outro problema, simplesmente falta vc pegar a variavel %localappdata% por outro meio, pq o DeleteFile não faz a expansão automática. Basta vc primeiro pegar das variáveis de ambiente em VB mesmo, e escrever assim: `My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile( meuLocalAppData + "\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History") `

Comment: @Bacco Já sei vou ativar o twitchTV ; Perai.

Comment: @Bacco você facebook ?

Comment: @Bacco ?: você consegue me ver nesse link ?
http://www.twitch.tv/icedoxforce

Comment: @Bacco resolvido ; 
* seu comando resolveu meu problema .

você respondeu em outro tópico mais tá tudo certo .
Shell("CMD.exe /c DEL /q ""%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History"" ")

Comment: @Perroni respondi lá, pq faz parte da mesma dúvida, senão vira muita bagunçe no site. Acho que você até poderia deletar esta aqui (o remover fica logo abaixo da pergunta), pois está tudo lá. Pena que você não entendeu o que o bigown quis dizer naquele post, pq era pra ajudar você a usar melhor o Site. Bom, o importante é que vc resolveu. Procure nas próximas perguntas a olhar os detalhes de como funciona o site, pois é vantagem pra você mesmo, e mais rápido de obter respostas boas.

Comment: @Bacco não consigo achar o botão pra deletar.

Comment: @Perroni com resposta postada não dá pra apagar, teria que deletar a resposta antes.

Answer (score -2):

```
Shell("CMD.exe /c DEL /q ""%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History"" ")
```

@Bacco , resposta dada por ele em outro tópico .